# Store/retrieve image in Artifactory using cURL

Tags: curl, multipartform-data, artifactory, form-data

I am using cURL to PUT image files to an Artifactory server, like so:

```
curl -u "username:pwd" -X PUT \
-F 'imageX=@/Users/me/my-images/cat.jpeg' \
http://maven.nabisco.com/artifactory/cdt-repo/folder/my-unique-file
```

When I download the file from the server, it looks like:

```
--------------------------7c3eb0ea54288120
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="cat_cat_cat.jpeg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

ˇÿˇ‡JFIFˇ€Ñ ( %!1"%)+...383-7(-.+
...yadda yadda yadda
```

so as far as I can tell, it's saving all of the form data onto the Artifactory server, not just the one file in the form data.

So three questions -

(a) is there some way to tell the server to just store the raw data from the one file in the form data?

(b) if I download the data from server, using cURL, is there some way to extract the image data from the form data, if I know the key of the form (in this case the key is "imageX")?

(c) is there a way to write a file with cURL without using form-data?

Comment: note that Artifactory does not seem to accept POST requests, just PUT

Comment: Artifactory also accepts POST requests, but it usually for updating and not for creation. See JFrog Artifactory REST API wiki page on: 

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API

Comment: Strange that POST is for updating, and PUT is for creation...!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, all you want to do is deploy an image and resolve it later on.
You can upload any file, without specifying the type of the file. in your scenario the command can even be more simple by using '-T' for sending the file, and using this you don't have to add the file name at the end of the Artifactory URL. It will take the name of the origin file:
curl -u "username:pwd" -T /Users/me/my-images/cat.jpeg "http://maven.nabisco.com/artifactory/cdt-repo/folder/"

Regarding the resolution of the file, all you need to do is:
curl -u "username:pwd" "http://maven.nabisco.com/artifactory/cdt-repo/folder/cat.jpeg" -O

(Adding the '-O' at the end will make sure that cURL will save the file as it is named on the remote server)

Comment: I had some success with --data-binary flag instead of -F, I haven't looked into -T flag...I don't think Artifactory can handle multipart data, that is the problem I originally faced.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I left the '-X PUT' for the deployment, where in fact it's not needed when using '-T'
So the upload command should be:

curl -u "username:pwd" -T /Users/me/my-images/cat.jpeg "http://maven.nabisco.com/artifactory/cdt-repo/folder/"

Comment: Thanks will take a look tomorrow